# Big Open Source Java applications/libraries

Tags: java, open-source

I am looking for big(more than 100 MB) open source Java projects.

Does Anyone know some?

Note: I am marking this as community wiki, though i am not sure if it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) - IDE and rich client platform
- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/community/sources/) - IDE and rich client platform
- [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) - Open source Java implementation
- [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) - Versatile library that supports many Java EE-like technologies
- [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/) - Java EE application server

Comment: Not sure spring sources are that big (if you remove documentation).

Answer (score 1):

[JBoss Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools) is a very large open source Java project. If you count the source, plus the separate Drools Solver and Drools Guvnor downloads, it comes out to about 86 MB. Throw in 31 MB of documentacion and apidocs and you have a project larger than 100 MB.

Answer (score 1):

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) is an open source UML Modeling tool developed in Java. I do not know of the exact size, but it is heavy and takes a while to load, which might make it a reference project for a complex tool.